# Permission denied to run kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run kafka on 3 machines as cluster, I have configured the Zookeeper on all the machines. Now I am trying to start the kafka server on 1 st machine using

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

It is giving error as

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh: line 44: /tmp/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka- 
run-class.sh: Permission denied
bin/kafka-server-start.sh: line 44: exec: /tmp/kafka/kafka_2.11- 
1.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Kafka installation is in the path /tmp/kafka/kafka_2.11- 
    1.1.0/  , and kafka logs are in the path /var/lib/kafka . 
I have logged in as root user. Still I am getting these errors. I Checked the permission of the .sh files in the bin of kafka directory. All those have execute permission for all. Please help me to solve this error.
Below are the links used to configure zookeeper and kafka

```
http://armourbear.blogspot.com/2015/03/setting-up-multinode-kafka- 
cluster.html
http://www.techburps.com/misc/multi-broker-apache-kafka-cluster-setup/64
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add commands you have typed to run all Kafka servers?

Comment: From the kafka directory i.e., /tmp/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/ I am running bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties command in all the machines

Comment: I even tried with "bash bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties" and "sh bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties" . Still not able to start kafka server

Comment: Is zookeeper running? And please tell me the exact  commands which you used to run kafka server.

Comment: You shouldn't put software you plan on executing as a server into /tmp

Comment: I changed the path to /var. Now its working. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like filesystem permissions problem, make sure that the /tmp is not mounted with noexec option. Or just try to set up kafka in another directory.

Comment: Yes after changing the path to /var directory it is working without any errors. Thank you so much